Let's get critical: Aug 2013 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Cognitive Sciences Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

If you see low quality questions you'd like deleted @Skippy, please flag them and/or post them to chat asking for support to delete them. A number of our users are in agreement with you that we should keep the site clean and you'll likely easily gain support in chat :-)

Final Results

Is there an accurate online IQ test for measuring 160+ IQs?
Net Score: 6 (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)  
Is there a psychological explanation for people being 'overcome by the Holy Spirit'?
Net Score: -2 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)  
How well can a human-generated "random number" be predicted?
Net Score: 7 (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)  
Does personality imply an inclination to be an expert in one field or average in "all" fields?
Net Score: 6 (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)  
Why do prices ending in 99, e.g., 0.99, 199 or 1999.9 convince consumers to buy?
Net Score: 6 (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)  
What makes someone attractive psychologically?
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)  
Why prefer "99% fat free" to "1% fat"?
Net Score: 5 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)  
Introductory material on psychophysics with a focus on visual stimuli
Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)  
Is there a function between loss of memory and time?
Net Score: 6 (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)  
Classic cognitive neuroscience studies that highlight conclusions that could not be drawn from behavioral experiments
Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)  

